# Isometry between the dual space $L^1(\mu)^*$ and $L^\infty(\mu)$. In need of a 'trial function'.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, measure-theory, vector-spaces

I am currently trying to show that $L^p(\mu)^*$ is isometrically isomorphic to $L^{p'}(\mu)$, where p' is the dual exponent. We are working in a $\sigma$-finite measure-space $(X,\mathcal{E}, \mu)$.

I am looking at the function $\Phi_p: L^{p'}(\mu) \to L^p(\mu)^*, f \mapsto \ell_f$, where $\ell_f([g])=\int_Xfg \, d\mu$ for $[g]\in L^p(\mu)$. Which I need to show is well-defined, norm-preserving and linear.

I have shown that $\Phi_p$ is well-defined and linear, and need further to show that it is norm-preserving. The norms are the usual $L^p$ norms and then the operator norm on the dual-space i.e. $\sup\{|\ell([g])|:\|g\|_p \leq 1\}$.

In general I have also shown that $\sup\{|\ell_f([g])\|:\|g\|_p \leq 1\} \leq\|f\|_{p'}$ i.e. that the ${p'}$ norm is an upper bound for the operator norm on $\ell_f$. Hence what I really need to show is that $\|f\|_{p'} \in \{|\ell_f([g])\|:\|g\|_p \leq 1\}$.

For the case $p>1, p'>1$ I did this by fixing some $f\in L^{p'}(\mu)$ and considering the function $g = \text{sgn}(f)\|f\|_{p'}^{1-p'}|f|^{p'-1}$. Which turned out to have a p-norm of 1, and for which $\bigg|\int_X fg \, d\mu\bigg| = \|f\|_{p'}$.

For the case where $p=1$ and $p' = \infty$ I am looking for at function like the one above, which can show that the infinity norm lies in the set. This is where I am stuck and could use some help.

Many thanks in advance.